# Easy way to see that harmonicity depends only on the connection of the target?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, vector-bundles, symmetry, connections

The concept of harmonicity of a map between Riemannian manifolds depends only on the Levi-Civita connection of the target manifold, as can be seen from the Euler-Lagrange equations (details below).

This is not trivial from the definition*, since the Dirichlet integral is explicitly dependent upon the metric of the taregt, not just its induced connection.

> Is there a way to "see in advance", **without deriving the Euler-Lagrange equations**, that the harmonicity will "turn out" to depend only upon the connection?

Another way to view this phenomena, is to think of it as an **additional symmetry** which is **"created"** when passing from the Dirichlrt energy functional to its associated E-L equations; While the original functional was not invariant under connection-preserving transformations, its set of critical points is invariant under such transformations.

> Is there a way then to see "in advance" the set of solutions to the E-L equations will have "more symmetries" than the functional? (inclusion in one way is obvious)

---

**Suggested approach:**

Suppose we somehow knew that the Euler-Lagrange equations, evaluated at a map $\phi:M \to N$ are of the form $\alpha_{M,N}(\phi)=0$, where in general $\alpha_{M,N}(\psi)$ takes values in $\Gamma(\psi^*TN)$. (Perhaps there is a way to deduce *that* somehow but let's leave it for now).

*This raises the following question:*

> Is this assumption, together with the known symmetry of isometry-invariance forces our operator to be the "right" one?

More precisely, consider pairs $(M,g),(N,h)$  of smooth Riemannian manifolds.

Are there any *non-zero* operators $\alpha_{M,N}$ which takes $\phi \in C^{\infty}(M,N)$ to $\Gamma(\phi^*TN)$ **and** are invariant under **"scaled isometries"**, other than $\alpha_{M,N}(\phi)=\operatorname{trace}_g(\nabla d\phi)=\delta(d\phi)$ (up to scaling)?

($\nabla$ is the tensor product connection of $\nabla^{T^*M},\phi^*(\nabla^{TN})$, where $\nabla^{T^*M}$ is the dual connection to the L-C connection on $TM$, $\nabla^{TN}$ is the L-C connection on $TN$).

By **"invariant"**, I mean that if $\phi:N \to \tilde N$ is a scaled isometry then

$$ d \tilde \phi \big(  \alpha_{M,N} (\phi) \big)=\alpha_{M,\tilde N} (\tilde \phi \circ \phi)$$

where I consider $ d \tilde \phi$ to as a map $\phi^*TN \to (\tilde \phi \circ \phi)^*T\tilde N$,

and I require similar invariance under compositions with scaled isometries from the left.

Perhaps I should also require that $\alpha_{M,N}$ will be dependent only upon $d\phi$ and its derivative.

**Comment:** Requiring only invariance under isometries (not including all scaled isometries), is not restrictive enough, e.g take

$$ \beta_{M,N} (\phi)=\| d\phi\|\operatorname{trace}_g(\nabla d\phi)=\| d\phi\|\delta(d\phi)$$

Then $\beta$ commutes with isometries,

$$ \beta_{M,\tilde N} (\tilde \phi \circ \phi)=\| d \tilde \phi \circ d\phi\|\delta(d \tilde \phi \circ d\phi)=\| d\phi\|d \tilde \phi\big(\delta(d\phi)\big)$$

$$ = d \tilde \phi\big(\| d\phi\|\delta(d\phi)\big)=d \tilde \phi \big(  \beta_{M,N} (\phi) \big)$$

but not with scaled isometries: If $\tilde \phi$ is a scaled isometry with conformal factor $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, then

$$ \beta_{M,\tilde N} (\tilde \phi \circ \phi)=\| d \tilde \phi \circ d\phi\|\delta(d \tilde \phi \circ d\phi)=\lambda\| d\phi\|d \tilde \phi\big(\delta(d\phi)\big)$$

$$ = \lambda d \tilde \phi\big(\| d\phi\|\delta(d\phi)\big)=\lambda d \tilde \phi \big(  \beta_{M,N} (\phi) \big)$$

**If the answer to the above question is positive, then this gives a nice explanation for the additional symmetry "created". It is the only possible outcome...**

---

*I am using the definition of harmonic maps as critical points of the Dirichlet functional.

**Proposition:**

Let $h,\tilde h$ be Riemannian metrics on a manifold $N$, with the same Levi-Civita connection.

Then $f:(M,g) \to (N,h)$ is harmonic $\iff$ $f:(M,g) \to (N,\tilde h)$ is harmonic.

**Proof:**

Let $\nabla=\nabla_h=\nabla_{\tilde{h}}$ be the L-C connection of $h,\tilde h$ on $TN$. Denote by $\nabla^{f^*TN}$ the pullback connection by $f$. The corresponding well-known E-L equations imply

$f:(M,g) \to (N,h)$ is harmonic $\iff \delta_h(df)=0$, where

$\delta_h:\Omega^1(M,f^*TN) \to \Omega^0(M,f^*TN)=\Gamma(f^*TN)$, is the adjoint of $\nabla^{f^*TN} $, taken w.r.t metrics $g,f^*h$ on $TM,f^*TN$.

Similarly,

$f:(M,g) \to (N,\tilde h)$ is harmonic $\iff \delta_{\tilde h}(df)=0$

Since both $f^*h,f^*{\tilde h}$ are metric w.r.t $\nabla^{f^*TN}$, and since the codifferential of $d_{\nabla^{f^*TN}}$ is [the same for every $\nabla^{f^*TN}$-compatible metric on $f^*TN$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2141312/why-the-codifferential-depends-only-on-the-connection-and-not-the-metric), we get that $\delta_{\tilde h}=\delta_h$.

Comment: @MoisheCohen I guess I failed to convey the right message. Dependence on $g$ is not equivalent to dependence on $\nabla^g$. Indeed, anything that depends on $\nabla^g$, depends on $g$, but not everything that depends on $g$ depends *only* on $\nabla^g$. The point is that $\nabla^g$ contains "less" information that $g$. (There can be truly different metrics with the same L-C connection, as you can see here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/339521/104576). So the fact that harmonicity depends only on the incuded L-C connection and *nothing but it* is not completely obvious.

Comment: As I stated in the question, two different metrics on the target which share the same L-C connection, give rise to the same concept of harmonicity. Could we deduce this in advance, without knowing the E-L equations?

Comment: @MoisheCohen BTW, I have sketched a possible idea which might be relevant (in the added "suggested approach"), However I might be entirely wrong there...